# Laravel : Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\\Excel\\Excel::load()

Tags: excel, laravel

when i want to running my import script, i have a trouble like this. i have replaced excel load() to excel import(), but this soltion doesn't work. what should i do to slove this trouble?
when i want to running my import script, i have a trouble like this. i have replaced excel load() to excel import(), but this soltion doesn't work. what should i do to slove this trouble?

```
 public function postImport(Request $request)
{
    // $this->validate($request, [
    //     'file'  => 'required|mimes:xls,xlsx'
    //    ]);
  
       $path = $request->file('file')->getRealPath();
  
       $data = Excel::load($path)->get();
    // $data = Excel::toArray([],$path);
       
  
       if($data->count() > 0)
       {
        foreach($data->toArray() as $key => $value)
        {
         foreach($value as $row)
         {
          $insert_data[] = array(
            'nomorUrut' => $row[0],
            'namaSupplier' => $row[1], 
            'singkatanSupplier' => $row[2], 
            'tipeSupplier' => $row[3], 
            'alamatSupplier' => $row[4], 
            'kodePosSupplier' => $row[5], 
            'noTelpSupplier' => $row[6], 
            'noFax' => $row[7],
            'emailSupplier' => $row[8],
            'contakSupplier' => $row[9],
            'hp' => $row[10],
          );
         }
        }
  
        if(!empty($insert_data))
        {
         DB::table('uplSupplier')->insert($insert_data);
        }
       }
       return back()->with('success', 'Excel Data Imported successfully.');
    //   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Load method is removed from the current version of Laravel Exel. You can consider to do:

Create a import class:

```
namespace App\Imports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToArray;

class InterfaceSupplier implements ToArray
{
    public function array(array $row)
    {}
}
```

Then:

```
   public function postImport(Request $request)
{
    $path = $request->file('file')->getRealPath();
    $data = Excel::toArray(new InterfaceSupplier(), $path);
    
    $data = $data[0];
    $insert_data = [];

    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $insert_data[] = [
            'nomorUrut' => $row[0],
            'namaSupplier' => $row[1],
            'singkatanSupplier' => $row[2],
            'tipeSupplier' => $row[3],
            'alamatSupplier' => $row[4],
            'kodePosSupplier' => $row[5],
            'noTelpSupplier' => $row[6],
            'noFax' => $row[7],
            'emailSupplier' => $row[8],
            'contakSupplier' => $row[9],
            'hp' => $row[10],
        ];
    }

    if (!empty($insert_data)) {
        DB::table('uplSupplier')->insert($insert_data);
    }

    return back()->with('success', 'Excel Data Imported successfully.');
}
```

If you want to use import method instead, reference https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/batch-inserts.html

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer,  i have followed your solution, and those solution make me face this other trouble ---- "Class \"App\\imports\\InterfaceSupplier\" not found"---- i dont why this happening, i have written those class in my controller any way.

Comment: Can you show your new code? it's better to Put UplSupplierImport in app\Imports folder

Comment: hello i have showed my new code on the top.

Comment: the new trouble is "Array to string conversion", should i do converting to solve this trouble?

Comment: I edited my answer. Hope it works!

Comment: If you want to use import method instead, reference https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/batch-inserts.html

Comment: hello, i have other case again, can you helm me agaian to slove this case? i want to call function from my DB, and i have written something like "  'idMember' => DB::select(" select dbo.fcIdMember(".$this->kodeToko.", '".$row[1]."') as idMember") ". is it true?

Comment: It seems the query is not correct. I can't grasp your issue well just through a very short comment.

Comment: i'm sorry, you can read my trouble in other place https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75982834/laravel-array-to-string-conversion?noredirect=1#comment134012640_75982834

Answer (score 0):

I've put `InterfaceSupplier( as UplSupplierImport )` in `app\Exports`. I have another trouble again, the trouble is "Array to string conversion". This is my new `InterfaceSupplier( as UplSupplierImport )` that I've put in my `app/export`. For the new code of the controller was same with you code before:

```
class InterfaceSupplier implements ToArray
{
    public function array(array $row)
    {
        return [
            'nomorUrut' => $row[0],
            'namaSupplier' => $row[1],
            'singkatanSupplier' => $row[2],
            'tipeSupplier' => $row[3],
            'alamatSupplier' => $row[4],
            'kodePosSupplier' => $row[5],
            'noTelpSupplier' => $row[6],
            'noFax' => $row[7],
            'emailSupplier' => $row[8],
            'contakSupplier' => $row[9],
            'hp' => $row[10],
        ];
    }
}
```

And this is the controller code:

```
public function postImport(Request $request)
{

    $path = $request->file('file')->getRealPath();
    $insert_data = Excel::toArray(new InterfaceSupplier(), $path);

    if(!empty($insert_data))
    {
        DB::table('uplSupplier')->insert($insert_data);
    }

    return back()->with('success', 'Excel Data Imported successfully.');
}
```