# Laravel : array to string conversion

Tags: excel, laravel, import

I want to import excel, and my code of controller is

```php
$path = $request->file('file')->getRealPath();
$dataOfMember = Excel::toArray(new InterfaceMember(), $path);
              
$dataOfMember = $dataOfMember[0];
$insert_dataOfMember = [];
          
foreach ($dataOfMember as $row) {
    $insert_dataOfMember[] = [
        'kodeToko' => $kodeToko = session('authData')['kodeToko'],
        'idMember' => DB::select(" select dbo.fcIdMember(".$this->kodeToko.", '".$row[1]."')"),
        'RefereceID' => $row[0],
        'KodeMember' => $row[1],
        'NamaMember' => $row[2], 
        'JenisIdentitas' => $row[3], 
        'NomorIdentitas' => $row[4], 
        'AlamatMember' => $row[5], 
        'KodePos' => $row[6], 
        'JenisKelamin' => $row[7], 
        'TglLahir' => $row[8], 
        'NoHp' => $row[9],
        'PointReedem' => $row[10],
        'RpMember' => $row[11],
    ];
}
          
if (!empty($insert_dataOfMember)) {
    DB::table('uplMemberDeposite')->insert($insert_dataOfMember);
}
          
return back()->with('success', 'Excel Data Imported successfully.');
```

when i running mya code,  i have error that ""Array to string conversion". What should i do to slove this error? anyone please help me!

Comment: What do you see when you do `dd(DB::select(" select dbo.fcIdMember(".$this->kodeToko.", '".$row[1]."')"))`

Comment: just id member (number and uniqe), i use stored procedur to import those data any way. when i import data i need to import idmember too, so i do that

Comment: Post the error trace.

Comment: Yes, but `DB::select(" select dbo.fcIdMember(".$this->kodeToko.", '".$row[1]."')")` is probably returning a `Collection` and not a single value.

Comment: i have traced. finally, i found that DB::select(" select dbo.fcIdMember(".$this->kodeToko.", '".$row[1]."')") make me face this error. but how am i run my code, i need data of id member. can you show me how to call function from DB?

Comment: DB::select(" select dbo.fcIdMember(".$this->kodeToko.", '".$row[1]."')") return a collection not a single value? so how to slove this trouble?

Comment: what shows up when you do `dd( DB::select(" select dbo.fcIdMember(".$this->kodeToko.", '".$row[1]."')") ); ` ?

Comment: just number (BIGINT) like 202304110001, when i throwed other kodetoko and $row[1] (idMember), will shows other result.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies with the line

```
'idMember' => DB::select("select dbo.fcIdMember(".$this->kodeToko.", '".$row[1]."')"),
```

`DB::select` returns an array according to the documentation.

If you did `dd(DB::select("select dbo.fcIdMember(".$this->kodeToko.", '".$row[1]."')"));`, I think you'd see the following on your screen:

```
array:1 [
  0 => {
    +"columnName": columnValue
  }
]
```

That's the array that is giving you the error. You're passing that entire array when what you're really trying to pass is the `columnValue` part.

---

```php
foreach ($dataOfMember as $row) {
    $result = DB::select(" select dbo.fcIdMember(".$this->kodeToko.", '".$row[1]."')");

    $insert_dataOfMember[] = [
        'kodeToko' => $kodeToko = session('authData')['kodeToko'],
        'idMember' => $result[0]->columnName, 
        'RefereceID' => $row[0],
        'KodeMember' => $row[1],
        'NamaMember' => $row[2], 
        'JenisIdentitas' => $row[3], 
        'NomorIdentitas' => $row[4], 
        'AlamatMember' => $row[5], 
        'KodePos' => $row[6], 
        'JenisKelamin' => $row[7], 
        'TglLahir' => $row[8], 
        'NoHp' => $row[9],
        'PointReedem' => $row[10],
        'RpMember' => $row[11],
    ];
}
```

Comment: When i dd those code, i face array:1 [▼ // app\Http\Controllers\ToolsInterfaceDataController.php:105
  0 => {#319 ▼
    +"": "202304110002"
  }
].  how i write $result[0]->columnName when my column name is empty?

Comment: maybe i'll write 'idMember' => $result. but this make me face the same error "Array to string conversion"

Comment: It's not empty. It has the key `""`. You can access it with `$result[0]->{""}`

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct. You just do a more small step:

```
$idMembers = DB::select("Select dbo.fcIdMember(".$this->kodeToko.", '".$row[1]."') as idMember");

$idMember = count($idMembers) ? $idMembers[0]->idMember : null;

//....  
$insert_dataOfMember[] = [
    //....     
   'idMember' => $idMember,
    //....     
];
//....
```

Comment: i forget about it. if i want to get some data specifically from document of excel, i mean like get data from cell with row 2 and column 3, how are you write the code? i written 'RefereceID' => $row[0, 1], thats doesn't run.

Comment: $dataOfMember[1][2]

Comment: hello, can you help me again? i faced a trouble about sweetalert, ajax, or something in my laravel project, this the page " https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76062500/laravel-how-to-make-sweetalert-close-when-data-have-been-loaded-in-data-base "