# Laravel : How to make Sweetalert close when data have been loaded in data base?

Tags: laravel, sweetalert

i run upload data in my project, i want sweetalert close when the data have been loaded in data base. this is my sweetalert code:

```
 document.getElementById('subImport').click();
            $(document).ready(function() {

                setTimeout(function() {
                    let timerInterval
                    Swal.fire({
                   
                    text:'Data Sedang Didownload!',
                    allowOutsideClick:false,
                  
                    background:'',
                    timer: 120000,
                    timerProgressBar: true,
                    didOpen: () => {
                        Swal.showLoading()
                        const b = Swal.getHtmlContainer().querySelector('b')
                       
                    },
                    willClose: () => {
                        clearInterval(timerInterval)
                    }
                    }).then((result) => {
                    /* Read more about handling dismissals below */
                    if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.timer) {
                        console.log('Data Sedang didownload')
                    }
                    })

                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function(data) {
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                
                                swal.close()
                                document.getElementById('subTampil').click();
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                document.getElementById("coba").hidden = true;
                                document.getElementById("divSupp").hidden = false;
                                document.getElementById("divMember").hidden = true;
                                document.getElementById("divItem").hidden = true;
                            }, 100)
                        }, 120100)
                        },
                    });
                    
                }, 100)
            })
```

i have been modificted my timer code, but it doesn't work. on the top was my recently code. i want the sweet alert is dinamis, not like on the top (statis with my size data)

Comment: put `let timerInterval;` outside of setTimeOut function 
`$(document).ready(function() {
    let timerInterval; 

    setTimeout(function() {
        Swal.fire({
            text: 'Data Sedang Didownload!',
            allowOutsideClick: false,
            background: '',
...` and check if it works

Comment: Change your `swal.close()` to `Swal.close()`.

Comment: same, the sweetalert closed before the data have been loaded all in data base. i have re-write swal.close() to Swal.close(), but same result.

Comment: Are you asking Sweetalert won't close or you want it close after request done?

Comment: Your code has too many redundant parts, it is recommended that you read the full Sweetalert documentation instead of just copy-pasting an example and modifying it.

Comment: i want sweetaler close when all data have loaded

Comment: If you want it close after loaded, using `$.ajax({ ... }).then(() => Swal.close())` instead of timer.